# MYSQL query doubt - storing selected value to variables

Tags: mysql

i am using a stored procedure. i declared 2 varaibles . shown below

```
DECLARE pProductCode          VARCHAR(15);

 DECLARE pProductVersion       VARCHAR(30);
```

i am selecting ProductCode and prodcuctVersion using a query from a table . shown below

```
 SELECT  ProductCode, ProductVersion
        FROM packages
       WHERE PackageID = pPackageID;
```

my question is how can i store the selected values productcode and productversion to the declared variables pProductCode and pProductVersion respectively.

i tried this

```
 SELECT pProductCode = ProductCode, pProductVersion = ProductVersion
        FROM packages
       WHERE PackageID = pPackageID;
```

but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL to store a column in a variable we use a [SELECT INTO statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into-statement.html).  For example:

```
SELECT ProductCode, ProductVersion
  INTO pProductCode, pProductVersion
  FROM packages
 WHERE PackageID = pPackageID;
```

`packageID` is a parameter.